# Highcharts. Highlight line chart date interval on hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart

I'm trying to implement highlight for a single section of line chart while hovering over this section. Under `section` I mean space between (in my case) vertical lines, which are representing separate date intervals depending on chart zoom level. The chart itself has dynamic data, which is being pulled from an endpoint with more detailed data, depending on date interval zoomed in.

During investigation I've found a `plotBands` property of `x/yAxis`. But the thing is, that this property only allows to set each `plotBand` manually.

So the question is, if there is something that will help me to do automatic creation of `plotBands` or similar hoverable/clickable stuff, for each separate time "interval"?

Comment: I think `plotBands` are exactly what you need to use. How do you calculate those vertical lines? If you know where are those vertical lines, then you know where `plotBand` should be added. You can also manage `plotBands` dynamically, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotBand). Here is a simple demo with events for `plotBand`: http://jsfiddle.net/nz093cvv/1/

Comment: The thing is, that in case with "Date" axis, tick values are calculated automatically based on zoom level. I believe I will be able to calculate `plotBands` dynamically, if there is a possibility to get current axis ticks values

Comment: To get ticks, use `chart.xAxis[0].tickPositions` :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the TestValue dynamically according to your needs and use something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abmadi/bb26cp3k/):

```
plotBands: [{ 
                color: '#FCFFC5',
                from: ($.TestValue)+1,
                to: ($.TestValue)+2
            },...]
```